# Unable to cat a data file into a script file (bash) on terminal command line

Tags: bash, macos, unix, command-line, terminal

Im new to bash, and  I am unable to cat a file and use the pipe command on the terminal using bash.

This is what ive tried on the terminal command line

```
$ cat data | readlooptest
```

however i always get this message when i use the pipe |

```
-bash: readlooptest: command not found
```

I have a Script named readlooptest, and a  data file

script contents of readlooptest

```
#!/bin/bash
read myLine
sum=0
for i in $myLine
do
    sum=`expr $sum + $i`
done
echo "sum is: $sum"
```

data file contents are

```
6 4 4 7 7
```

So once the commands are entered in terminal, the output should be

```
$ chmod +x readlooptest
$ cat data | readlooptest
sum is : 28
```

However I get

```
-bash: readlooptest: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with piping or `cat`. The actual problem is that you need to specify *where* `readlooptest` is, since it's not in your [`PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111550/117037). If it's in the working directory, simply add `./` to the start:

```
$ cat data | ./readlooptest
```

Answer (score 2):

If `readlooptest` is not installed in one of your `$PATH` directories, you have to give the path to it to run it.

So for your piped `cat`, if you are `cd` in the same directory as `readlooptest`:

```sh
cat data | ./readlooptest
```

Comment: You might want to mention that `cat` is unnecessary here (cf. `./readlooptest < data`)

Comment: Indeed, but there was so much to mention like the antiquated use of back-ticks and expr, that I thought the poster was learning on an old book. No big deal, and there will be plenty of occasions to appreciate optimized and more modern constructs once the basic issues like command not found in path are assimilated no more issues.

Comment: It is typically termed a *UUOc* (Unnecessary Use Of `cat`). Helpful to let them know if they are using `cat` for anything other than concatenating two files together (or dumping a short file to `stdout` to look at the contents), then their use of `cat` is likely a *UUOc* `:)`

Comment: @LéaGris indeed: the UUOc (to borrow David's remark :) is not the single pitfall to encounter when learning Bash! Anyway, this makes me think it could be useful to mention that very nice reference on POSIX and Bash shell scripting: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ (if only I was told it years ago :)